# How to receive whole message if message contain more then 160 characters?

Tags: node.js, serial-port, gsm, modem

I have wavecom GSM(16 port) modem I operate it with node js
When I receive message that contain more then 160 character at that time I receive message like this

```
+CMT: "+919800000000",,"12/04/17,20:03:27+22"
@o09 @ hello hi ?1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 

+CMT: "+919800000000",,"12/04/17,20:03:34+22"
@o09­@ rest message 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890

+CMT: "+919800000000",,"12/04/17,20:03:40+22"
@o09¨@ rest message ,,,,,...
```

Here first and second message contain 160 character(Assume it, I write this message manually) 
I receive anonymous characters at begging of the message(Like: @o09­@ ) 
How can I receive whole message in one block 
Like this

```
+CMT: "+919800000000",,"12/04/17,20:03:27+22"
hello hi ?1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890  rest message 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 rest message ,,,,,...
```

Info : I initialize my all port with 115200 baud rate.

Is there any at command which solve my problem.?
Thanks in Advance....